# The argument type 'List<CommentData>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-listview

I'm trying to build the the listview with the data queried from firebase. But I'm having an error 'The argument type 'List < CommentData >' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List< Widget >' The code is as follows

```
    Widget buildComments() {
    if (this.didFetchComments == false) {
      return FutureBuilder<List<CommentData>>(
          future: commentService.getComments(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Container(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator());

            this.didFetchComments = true;
            this.fetchedComments = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data,  // where i'm having error
            );
          });
    } else {
      return ListView(children: this.fetchedComments); 
    }
  }
```

How can i work around this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` expects a `List<Widgets>` but you are passing `List<CommentData>`

You can modify your `ListView` to the following to rectify the error.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text(snapshot.data[index]['key']); //Any widget you want to use.
    },

);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error speak itself

> The argument type '`List<CommentData>`' can't be assigned to the parameter type '`List<Widget>`'

If you want to create List `Text` widget for showing comment, you can use

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(snapshot.data[index].*), //What ever you want to show in from your model
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot.data` returns `List<CommentData>` while ListView's children requires a List of Widgets, thus you get that error.

Try changing

```
return ListView(
   children: snapshot.data,
);
```

to something like:

```
return ListView(
   children: Text(snapshot.data[index].userName), //change userName to whatever field of CommentData class you want to show
);
```

I would recommend using `ListView.Builder` to work with Lists and indexes.